# Python Path - Get Directory To access in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to python.

I want to access a file using path.

My Directory looks like this

```
main_folder
├───backend
│   └───src
│       ├───apps
│       │   └───frontendreact/views.py
├───frontend
│   └───src
│   └───templates
│       ├───index.html
```

I have witten in code.

```
def index(request):
    import os
    print('\n')

    print(os.getcwd()) # This print -->> D:\main_folder\backend\src

    print('\n')
    return render(request, '../../frontend/templates/frontend/index.html')
```

Above code is giving me error - `TemplateDoesNotExist at /`

But I want to access the file which is in `main_folder/frontend/templates/index.html`.

But my python file from where i am calling path is in `main_folder/backend/src/apps/frontendreact/views.py.html`

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to access the file which is in main_folder/frontend/templates/index.html.

If that's the case you need to change the last line of your code to `return render(request, '../../frontend/templates/index.html')`